# Twilio Flow - Http Request with input parameters from previous step

Tags: twilio

I have 1 number in Twilio which I want to use for all my clients.

I want to create the following flow:

Receive a sms message -> match the body by some value(number 1-1000, using that value I want to identify which client this is) -> send an `Http` reqeust to my server with the matched number + `From` phone number.

So far I have matched the number from the body. Now I want to send an `Http` reqeust with the input parameters but I don't see an option to add the `From` or the `Body` of the `SMS` as an input to the `Http` request.

Is this even possible with Twilio?

[image: twilio]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, these would be HTTP Request Parameters of the Studio [HTTP Request Widget](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/widget-library/http-request). Use liquid/mustache syntax with your keys for those values. The values come in via the Studio [Trigger Widget](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/widget-library/trigger-start).

`{{trigger.message.From}}`

`{{trigger.message.Body}}`

You can use the Studio Execution logs to see other the values and their associated path.

[image]